# Download an epub file through axios & react-file-download lbraries in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, epub

I am trying to fetch an epub file from my server using axios and [react-file-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-download). The download code looks as follows -

```
const FileDownload = require('react-file-download');
export const handleDownload = (url, bookName) => {
  axios.get(url).then((res) => {
    FileDownload(res.data, bookName+'.epub');
  });
}
```

The file is downloaded. I see different size on disc for different books. But they just don't open. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

For epub files the content type is like "application/epub+zip"
Try this instead.

Thanks
Saptha

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at the `responseType` config option that axios provides.](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config)

You may need to add `{responseType 'blob'}` to the config - that's what got downloading PDF files working for me.